# Parsing JSON in "R"

Tags: r, json, parsing

I'm learning "R" so this question might be trivial for most of you.

I want to create Data Frame from [JSON data](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo).

JSON Looks like this:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-05-17 10:01:49",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2019-05-17": {
        "1. open": "128.3050",
        "2. high": "129.0600",
        "3. low": "128.2700",
        "4. close": "128.8200",
        "5. volume": "3817460"
    },
    "2019-05-16": {
        "1. open": "126.7500",
        "2. high": "129.3800",
        "3. low": "126.4600",
        "4. close": "128.9300",
        "5. volume": "29676333"
    },
 ...
 }
}
```

And I want to parse it to single table with columns `day|open|high|low|close|volume`

Can I do it without for loops?

Comment: There are existing accessors for the Alphavantage service you could use, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=alphavantage

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks, I didn't know that, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in your data set with `fromJSON()` from the `jsonlite` package:

```
x=fromJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo')
```

Unstack the resultant the time series sub-list with `plyr:ldply`, then transform data from long to wide with `spread()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
x2 = spread(plyr::ldply(x$`Time Series (Daily)`, stack), key = ind, value = 'values')
```

Rename columns as desired:

```
colnames(x2) = c('day', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume')
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse a JSON file it's best to use `jsonlite` library. It works perfectly with "easy" JSON files, that could be parsed directly into a data frame. However, your input file is not that easy, so you need to break down reading the files into several steps to obtain a nicely formatted data frame.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringi)
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, fromJSON("./example.json")[[2]]))
dates <- as.Date(rownames(df), format="%Y-%m-%d")
df <- df %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% add_column(dates, .before=1)
colnames(df) <- stri_trans_totitle(stri_replace_all_regex(colnames(df), "X\\d\\.\\.", ""))
```

x
Please mind that I've taken the second element of the (initial) list read by `fromJSON` function, as the first entry is your metadata. The rest of the code are bells and whistles to get desired form of the frame. If you want to have dates as row names rather than a column in a frame, use `tibble::column_to_rownames()` function.